# How to force keep blank from the edge

Tags: html, css

The sections are just stick on the edges,

I want them to keep from the edges,

How to do it ?

I've tried padding, and margin , but it didn't work.

### CSS

```
.cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more, .cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
  display: inline-block;
}
.cd-timeline-content p {
  margin: 1em 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
.cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more {
  float: right;
  padding: .8em 1em;
  background: #acb7c0;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
.no-touch .cd-timeline-content .cd-read-more:hover {
  background-color: #bac4cb;
}
.cd-timeline-content .cd-date {
  float: left;
  padding: .8em 0;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

[image][image]

Comment: you need to add your markup, it's impossible to tell from an image what your markup is and what is your CSS referencing

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly clear from your screen captures which elements are which.. but in general, if you want to center something place it in a div (perhaps a nested div element) and then add `margin: 0 auto`.. note: in order to center something left/right it must have defined width...

And you need to watch postioning closely.. float: left , float: right will push things in those directions...

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="width: 200px, margin: 0 auto;"> content of interest  </div>
</div>
```